# Iniciar processo com nome personalizado via linha de comando

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Existe um processo na minha aplicação que hoje sempre que roda mantem o nome da função como o nome do processo em background.

Entretanto para realizar alguns mapeamentos, queria personalizar o nome do processo em background.

Baseado em alguns exemplos da internet, cheguei até o seguinte modelo, entretanto não está funcionando como deveria.

Utilizei uma notação que é: `bash -c "exec -a <NomeDoProcesso> <Comando>"`

No meu caso, meu script no momento está dessa forma:

```
bash -c "exec -a <NomeDoProcesso> nohup php index.php <Controller> <NomeDaFunção> > /var/www/log/ArquivoLog.log 2>&1 &"
```

Entretanto ele ainda continua puxando sempre o **Nome da Função** como o nome do processo que fica em background, e não o **Nome do Processo** que eu defini.

Existe algo errado no meu script ou realmente não é possível subir o processo com um nome personalizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é criar um link simbolico com o nome que deseja apontando para o programa que ira ser executado. Exemplo:

**foo**

```
echo "$0 args $@"
```

**bar**

```
ln -s "foo" "novo-nome"
bash "novo-nome" "$@"
```

Teste:

```
chmod +x foo bar

./foo foo1 foo2
foo args foo1 foo2

./bar bar1 bar2
novo-nome args bar1 bar2
```

Mas no seu caso acho que vc poderia criar um script e chamar ele direto, ex:

**novo-nome.sh**

```
php index.php <Controller> <NomeDaFunção> > /var/www/log/ArquivoLog.log
```

**teste**

```
chmod +x novo-nome.sh
nohup novo-nome.sh
```

Comment: Então, até entendi sua sugestão e agradeço pela contribuição. Mas por exemplo no meu caso, eu precisaria que o nome do processo seja dinâmico baseado em uma variável minha, até por isso que dentro de uma função de PHP eu dou o `exec()` pra executar no bash. Não sei se deixei isso muito claro na pergunta, essa em si que é minha dificuldade.

Comment: Nesse caso como precisaria chamar o `exec()` no php até para definir o nome do processo, não caberia eu utilizar um arquivo `.sh` para isso.

Comment: Vc não foi claro. A postagem esta marcada como bash e ubuntu, e não php.  E pelo que esta escrito na sua publicação vc esta usando o shell pra chamar a execução de um script php.

Comment: Você está correto. Darei como respondida pois testei sua proposta de solução e atende o que eu apresentei na pergunta.